# Fast Evolutionary Algorithm Mutation: Mutating n random genes instead of evaluating every gene

Tags: python, numpy, genetic-algorithm, mutation

I'm trying to optimize the code for my genetic algorithm. The DNA is currently a dictionary to increase lookup speeds for fitness calculations, but can be easily changed to a numpy array.

The mutation rate is supposed to be 1/L, L being the length of the DNA.

This solution works, but it's quite slow:

```py
# Iterate through genome, flip a gene with a probability of 1/L
def mutate(self):
      self.dna = dict(
        [(i, flip(self.dna[i])) if random.randint(0,num_genes) < 1 
        else (i, self.dna[i]) for i in range(num_genes)]
        )
```

This solution is about twice as fast, but for some reason it produces much worse results:

```py
# Select n number of genes calculated by 1/L, then change n random genes
def mutate(self):
      num_mutations = sum(np.random.choice([0,1], num_genes, p=[(num_genes-1)/num_genes, 1/num_genes]))
      for i in np.random.choice(num_genes-1, num_mutations):
        self.dna[i] = flip(self.dna[i])
```

As far as I can tell they mutate the same number of genes, and the output should be the same. 10 runs of both with set random seeds show that the latter approach results in way worse fitness results however.

**Why does the second approach result in worse dna fitness?** How do these approaches differ in their outcome?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Have you tried using `np.random.binomial` and generate for size=`num_genes`?

Comment: @dgumo thank you for you suggestion, tried that now. It's a mite faster, but the results are the same as using random.choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## First off: the vectorization

There's no point in using a dict when your indices are integers - looking up an integer index is always faster than using a hash-table.  Also you can vectorize this using numpy - make your `self.dna` a numpy array instead of a list or a dict, which may make for a 10x-100x speedup.

```
def flip(x):  # x is a vector of genes, lets a binary array here
    return ~x
mutation_mask = np.random.rand(n_genes)<1./len(self.dna)
self.dna[mutation_mask] = flip(dna[mutation_mask])
```

## Second off: Why your two algorithms are different:

I don't know, they look like they should be the same statistically.  The one thing I can think is that in the second you're modifying `self.dna` in place with `self.dna[i]=...`, rather than reassigning `self.dna=...`, so any other area in the code that has a the old `self.dna` will have their copy changed too in the second case. You could fix this by inserting `self.dna = self.dna.copy()` before your for-loop in the second example.

Comment: Thank you Peter, your intuition on why the algorithms differed was correct and solved my problem. My first approach was also to use vectors, but I saw speed losses compared to dicts due to my fitness function basically being a list comprehension with lookups. I guess I have some work to do to re-write it using vector operations instead.

Answer (score 1):

The complexity is due to the multiple calls to random: You are calling it for each gene.

Your second example does the same but this time they are all called in the same function.

A way to drastically improve the performance is to reduce the number of random calls. For that, you can use some math to know beforehand how many mutations a genome will receive, the formula is the following

```
P(L, n, p) # probability of modifying n-times a genome of size L with a succes p (here p is 1/L)
P(L, n, p) = binomial(n, L) * p**n * (1-p)**(L-n)
```

If you are not too familiar with math, here is a python function that will do that for you:

```
def binomial(n, k):
    if 0 <= k <= n:
        ntok = ktok = 1
        for t in range(1, min(k, n - k) + 1):
            ntok *= n; ktok *= t; n -= 1
        return ntok // ktok
    else: return 0

def P(L, n, p): return binomial(L, n) * p**n * (1-p)**(L-n)
```

And now you can pre-compute that and keep it in a list:

```
proba = [P(L, i, 1/L) for i in range(0, L+1)]
```

Also I will recommand partially summing it for easier use of random

```
probaS = [sum(proba[:k]) for k in range(0, L+1)] + [1]
```

Now you can generate only one random number and you will directly know how many mutations you need for this genome:

```
r = random()
i = 0
while r > probaS[i]: i += 1
```

At the end of the loop, i-1 will tell you how many mutations are needed.

Now you just have to select randomly i-1 different part of the genome and this is done! You went from L random calls to only 2 or 3 on average.

On the basic test I conducted, the time complexity for L=50 and 100,000 genomes went from 5.74s to 196ms so about 30 times faster.

My answer is a bit technical so feel free to ask if it wasn't clear.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Philippe, that sped up the calculations considerably. However, I still have the problem that this somehow affects the fitness of the solution. Do you have any idea why this would happen?

Comment: Well, unless you're working with a specific lucky seed, I don't see why this should be different. Did you run it multiple times and got accurately lower performances? Also, I didn't included that but you should make sure the (i-1) indices of the genome you are generating are distinct

Comment: As commented in the answer by Peter, the issue had to do with changes to DNA not being propagated because it was changed in place.

Answer (score 0):

In the first example you are potentially mutating your genes more than num_mutations times. While your first method has on average num_mutations mutations, the fact that it sometimes is greater can be leveraged by your crossover function which will potentially contribute that more diverse gene into the pool. Ideally, your fitness function is able to discard bad permutations while capitalizing on potentially more diverse candidates that diversify the pool.

Additionally, mutating in chunks will tend to produce faster yet worse results. Because mutations are not homogenized as smoothly across the gene, then it is possible that a certain chunk will be mutated such that it skews the pool fitnesses and can potentially be disproportionately picked. Because the mutations are not homogenized, you are potentially missing out on the work that is done by mutating other genes that may not have as much impact on the fitness. This is one of the biggest pitfalls using exponential fitness functions, if you are doing that, as this will exponentiate this discrepancy. If you were to homogenize the random choice over the gene, this potentially much fitter gene would have a much more diverse contribution to the solution space search. There are several ways to easily get by this such as forcing fittest solutions to breed with other pool members without gene replacement if there are enough genes in a population.